# Displaying date and time in the UI

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

My program displays the current date and time and must be accurate, and I need to prevent users from changing the time. Here's what I tried.

On form load I query the current date and time of the server and change the local system time to what I got.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   cmd = New SqlCommand("Select getdate()", con)
   serverdatetime = cmd.ExecuteScalar
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.TimeOfDay = serverdatetime
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Today = serverdatetime
   TimeKeeper.Start()
End Sub
```

Now I tried 2 ways of displaying the time, the first one, since I adjusted the system time to what I got from the server, I just get my time from the local system. But the time on my program can easily be changed by changing the system time.

```
Private Sub TimeKeeper_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimeKeeper.Tick
    lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.Date()
    lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now().ToString("HH:mm:ss")
End SUb
```

Second thing, I just take the time I got from the server and increment it every second.

```
Private Sub TimeKeeper_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimeKeeper.Tick
    serverdatetime = serverdatetime.AddSeconds(1)
    lblDate.Text = serverdatetime.Date()
    lblTime.Text = serverdatetime.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
End SUb
```

I thought it worked great except it seems to get delayed once I do some operations in the system(I guess because some other code is running, my timer doesn't execute its code) and the more I do the more it gets delayed, after a few testing of the program the server time was already 10 seconds ahead of the time I have in my program.

So, how can I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rely on Tick event of the Timer. I would use the [StopWatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) class to get duration passed (since when server time is read) independent from the system time adjustments.

```
Dim stopWatch As StopWatch = new StopWatch()
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   cmd = New SqlCommand("Select getdate()", con)
   serverdatetime = cmd.ExecuteScalar
   stopWatch.Start()
   TimeKeeper.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub TimeKeeper_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimeKeeper.Tick
    Dim currentDate As DateTime = serverdatetime.Add(stopWatch.Elapsed)      
    lblDate.Text = currentDate.Date()
    lblTime.Text = currentDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
End SUb
```